# Is there a way to make a Google sheets cell display multiple hyperlinks (one per line in the tooltip) when selected?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I develop this spreadsheet here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ye_HTjC_jrExwMDPM2X1mtXhSDQOtjg841SzBno0ExU/

Essentially, someone hosts a period of multiple tournaments corresponding to various timeslots throughout the week, and they post a final round replay (URL) of each tournament in one cell: Column G in the 'Chronology' sheet. So every cell in Column G, contains a list of replays, e.g. `http://a`, `http://b`, `http://c` (if there were 3 tournaments).

One day, less than a month ago, I was pleasantly surprised to discover a hyperlink of each replay appeared on each line in the tooltip when I selected the latest replay cell. I got really excited, and decided to trigger it for cells (I think I spammed the return key). I assumed the way to trigger would stay, but it seems to me it's now been altered so it won't result in multiple hyperlinks being displayed in the tooltip.

You can see a good use of it in Row 988 (984th edition), but it's gone by Row 991 (987th edition).

So my question is, is there a way to code this in the script editor or a way to still trigger this in the spreadsheet itself?

Comment: How did you trigger it for the cells for which it worked? Did you populate all the cells in the same way? What I can see so far is that your issue seems to be related to the content of the cells: If you copy the content of the cells, where it is not working into a text file - you will see that the links are separated by line breaks, while in the cells where it works - there are no breaks between the entries. Also, if you remove one of the entries for the cells where the hovering works - it will stop working.

Comment: The trigger seemed to be on edit, with only the first cell (of all the edited cells) URL tooltip being updated. I had to use the return key on literally every cell (900+ of them), since iirc paste/fill only updated the first . Each URL is delimited by `, ` with more or less space in between. Empty replays are represented by ` `.  CRLF only appears to indicate the next Row to me when I copy. I don't see any difference other than in the tooltips.

Comment: May I ask you where the data is coming from? Is it retrieved from a source where it is already pre-formatted?

Comment: There's 30-odd users with access. The user who runs the tournaments for the specific time period, fills in the corresponding row. There's a macro to make sure the  row is added with the correct cell formatting. You ought to see this thread anyway: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/5130196?hl=en . I assume developers from google updated stuff at some point, but I'm not sure if it's communicated anywhere publicly online. I'm guessing there's no alternate way to replicate this seemingly unintended feature.